# Wordpress query is not returning proper results

Tags: database

I am getting data from query in this query data is coming from different filters each and every filter is working properly and getting correct results but when ever I select country all other filters returns no record in fact all the record from that country returns I am debugging this issue for about 6 hours now but nothing happens anyone please help me out with this issue here is what I am doing

The function where I am making the query.

```
public function pre_get_posts( $q ) {

// check if the user is requesting an admin page 
if ( is_admin() || ! $q->is_main_query() )
    return;

if ( ! is_post_type_archive( 'auto-listing' ) )
    return;

if ( ! is_search() )
    return;

$meta_query = array();

$year_query[]       = $this->year_query();
$make_query[]       = $this->make_query();
$model_query[]      = $this->model_query();
$condition_query[]  = $this->condition_query();
$odometer_query[]   = $this->odometer_query();
$price_query[]      = $this->price_meta_query();
$body_type_query    = $this->body_type_query();
$country_query          = $this->country_query();
$transmission_query     = $this->transmission_query();
$radius_query[]     = $this->radius_query( $q );

$query_1 = array_merge( $country_query, $year_query, $model_query, 
$condition_query, $price_query, $odometer_query, $transmission_query );
var_dump($query_1);
// if our rasius query fails, fall back to keyword searching
// will fail with no map API key
if( empty( $radius_query[0] ) || ! $radius_query[0] ) {
    $keyword_query[] = $this->keyword_query( $q );
    $query_2 = $keyword_query;
} else {
    $query_2 = $radius_query;
}

// if no keyword
if ( empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
            echo 'HERE';
    $query_1['relation'] = 'AND';
    $meta_query[] = $query_1;
}

// if keyword
if ( ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
            echo '!HERE';
    $query_2['relation'] = 'OR';
    $meta_query[] = $query_1;
    $meta_query[] = $query_2;
    $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';
}

$q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

$q->set( 'tax_query', $body_type_query ); 

$q->set( 'post_type', 'auto-listing' ); 

// echo '<pre>';print_r($q);


 }
```

And here is the country query function

```
/**
 * Returns a meta query for filtering by country.
 * @return type
 */
  private function country_query() {
  if ( isset( $_GET['country'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['country'] ) ) {
  $data = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', wp_unslash( 
  $_GET['country'] ) );
  return array(
    'key'       => '_al_listing_country', 
    'value'     => $data,
    'compare'   => 'IN'

);
 }
 return array();
}
```

I don't know what is it that I am doing wrong if anyone can track this issue would be a great help.

**var_export result with country**

```
WP_Query::__set_state( array(
    'query' => array(
        's' => '',
        'post_type' => 'auto-listing',
        'model' => array(
            0 => 'F12 Berlinetta',
            1 => 'California',
        ),
        'condition' => array(
            0 => 'New',
            1 => 'Used',
        ),
        'min_price' => '',
        'max_price' => '',
        'odometer' => '',
        'within' => '',
        'country' => array(
            0 => 'Pakistan',
            1 => 'United Kingdom',
        ),
    ),
    'query_vars' => array(
        's' => '',
        'post_type' => 'auto-listing',
        'model' => array(
            0 => 'F12 Berlinetta',
            1 => 'California',
        ),
        'condition' => array(
            0 => 'New',
            1 => 'Used',
        ),
        'min_price' => '',
        'max_price' => '',
        'odometer' => '',
        'within' => '',
        'country' => array(
            0 => 'Pakistan',
            1 => 'United Kingdom',
        ),
        'error' => '',
        'm' => '',
        'p' => 0,
        'post_parent' => '',
        'subpost' => '',
        'subpost_id' => '',
        'attachment' => '',
        'attachment_id' => 0,
        'name' => '',
        'static' => '',
        'pagename' => '',
        'page_id' => 0,
        'second' => '',
        'minute' => '',
        'hour' => '',
        'day' => 0,
        'monthnum' => 0,
        'year' => 0,
        'w' => 0,
        'category_name' => '',
        'tag' => '',
        'cat' => '',
        'tag_id' => '',
        'author' => '',
        'author_name' => '',
        'feed' => '',
        'tb' => '',
        'paged' => 0,
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => '',
        'preview' => '',
        'sentence' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'menu_order' => '',
        'embed' => '',
        'category__in' => array(),
        'category__not_in' => array(),
        'category__and' => array(),
        'post__in' => array(),
        'post__not_in' => array(),
        'post_name__in' => array(),
        'tag__in' => array(),
        'tag__not_in' => array(),
        'tag__and' => array(),
        'tag_slug__in' => array(),
        'tag_slug__and' => array(),
        'post_parent__in' => array(),
        'post_parent__not_in' => array(),
        'author__in' => array(),
        'author__not_in' => array(),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date ID',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'meta_query' => array(
            0 => array(
                'key' => '_al_listing_country',
                'value' => array(
                    0 => 'Pakistan',
                    1 => 'United Kingdom',
                ),
                'compare' => 'IN',
                0 => array(),
                1 => array(
                    'key' => '_al_listing_model_name',
                    'value' => array(
                        0 => 'F12 Berlinetta',
                        1 => 'California',
                    ),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
                2 => array(
                    'key' => '_al_listing_condition',
                    'value' => array(
                        0 => 'New',
                        1 => 'Used',
                    ),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
                3 => array(),
                4 => array(),
                'relation' => 'AND',
            ),
        ),
        'tax_query' => NULL,
    ),
    'tax_query' => WP_Tax_Query::__set_state( array(
        'queries' => array(),
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'table_aliases' => array(),
        'queried_terms' => array(),
        'primary_table' => NULL,
        'primary_id_column' => NULL,
    )),
    'meta_query' => false,
    'date_query' => false,
    'post_count' => 0,
    'current_post' => -1,
    'in_the_loop' => false,
    'comment_count' => 0,
    'current_comment' => -1,
    'found_posts' => 0,
    'max_num_pages' => 0,
    'max_num_comment_pages' => 0,
    'is_single' => false,
    'is_preview' => false,
    'is_page' => false,
    'is_archive' => true,
    'is_date' => false,
    'is_year' => false,
    'is_month' => false,
    'is_day' => false,
    'is_time' => false,
    'is_author' => false,
    'is_category' => false,
    'is_tag' => false,
    'is_tax' => false,
    'is_search' => true,
    'is_feed' => false,
    'is_comment_feed' => false,
    'is_trackback' => false,
    'is_home' => false,
    'is_404' => false,
    'is_embed' => false,
    'is_paged' => false,
    'is_admin' => false,
    'is_attachment' => false,
    'is_singular' => false,
    'is_robots' => false,
    'is_posts_page' => false,
    'is_post_type_archive' => true,
    'query_vars_hash' => '75c1fa23a84337dc910c0b799ec43e27',
    'query_vars_changed' => false,
    'thumbnails_cached' => false,
    'stopwords' => NULL,
    'compat_fields' => array(
        0 => 'query_vars_hash',
        1 => 'query_vars_changed',
    ),
    'compat_methods' => array(
        0 => 'init_query_flags',
        1 => 'parse_tax_query',
    ),
));
```

**var_export result without country.**

```
WP_Query::__set_state( array(
    'query' => array(
        's' => '',
        'post_type' => 'auto-listing',
        'model' => array(
            0 => 'F12 Berlinetta',
            1 => 'California',
        ),
        'condition' => array(
            0 => 'New',
            1 => 'Used',
        ),
        'min_price' => '',
        'max_price' => '',
        'odometer' => '',
        'within' => '',
    ),
    'query_vars' => array (
        's' => '',
        'post_type' => 'auto-listing',
        'model' => array(
            0 => 'F12 Berlinetta',
            1 => 'California',
        ),
        'condition' => array(
            0 => 'New',
            1 => 'Used',
        ),
        'min_price' => '',
        'max_price' => '',
        'odometer' => '',
        'within' => '',
        'error' => '',
        'm' => '',
        'p' => 0,
        'post_parent' => '',
        'subpost' => '',
        'subpost_id' => '',
        'attachment' => '',
        'attachment_id' => 0,
        'name' => '',
        'static' => '',
        'pagename' => '',
        'page_id' => 0,
        'second' => '',
        'minute' => '',
        'hour' => '',
        'day' => 0,
        'monthnum' => 0,
        'year' => 0,
        'w' => 0,
        'category_name' => '',
        'tag' => '',
        'cat' => '',
        'tag_id' => '',
        'author' => '',
        'author_name' => '',
        'feed' => '',
        'tb' => '',
        'paged' => 0,
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => '',
        'preview' => '',
        'sentence' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'menu_order' => '',
        'embed' => '',
        'category__in' => array(),
        'category__not_in' => array(),
        'category__and' => array(),
        'post__in' => array(),
        'post__not_in' => array(),
        'post_name__in' => array(),
        'tag__in' => array(),
        'tag__not_in' => array(),
        'tag__and' => array(),
        'tag_slug__in' => array(),
        'tag_slug__and' => array(),
        'post_parent__in' => array(),
        'post_parent__not_in' => array(),
        'author__in' => array(),
        'author__not_in' => array(),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date ID',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'meta_query' => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => array(),
                1 => array(
                    'key' => '_al_listing_model_name',
                    'value' => array(
                        0 => 'F12 Berlinetta',
                        1 => 'California',
                    ),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
                2 => array(
                    'key' => '_al_listing_condition',
                    'value' => array(
                        0 => 'New',
                        1 => 'Used',
                    ),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
                3 => array(),
                4 => array(),
                'relation' => 'AND',
            ),
        ),
        'tax_query' => NULL,
    ),
    'tax_query' => WP_Tax_Query::__set_state( array(
        'queries' => array(),
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'table_aliases' => array(),
        'queried_terms' => array(),
        'primary_table' => NULL,
        'primary_id_column' => NULL,
    )),
    'meta_query' => false,
    'date_query' => false,
    'post_count' => 0,
    'current_post' => -1,
    'in_the_loop' => false,
    'comment_count' => 0,
    'current_comment' => -1,
    'found_posts' => 0,
    'max_num_pages' => 0,
    'max_num_comment_pages' => 0,
    'is_single' => false,
    'is_preview' => false,
    'is_page' => false,
    'is_archive' => true,
    'is_date' => false,
    'is_year' => false,
    'is_month' => false,
    'is_day' => false,
    'is_time' => false,
    'is_author' => false,
    'is_category' => false,
    'is_tag' => false,
    'is_tax' => false,
    'is_search' => true,
    'is_feed' => false,
    'is_comment_feed' => false,
    'is_trackback' => false,
    'is_home' => false,
    'is_404' => false,
    'is_embed' => false,
    'is_paged' => false,
    'is_admin' => false,
    'is_attachment' => false,
    'is_singular' => false,
    'is_robots' => false,
    'is_posts_page' => false,
    'is_post_type_archive' => true,
    'query_vars_hash' => '53d40a59288cf391a5bf428c30c6ae21',
    'query_vars_changed' => false,
    'thumbnails_cached' => false,
    'stopwords' => NULL,
    'compat_fields' => array(
        0 => 'query_vars_hash',
        1 => 'query_vars_changed',
    ),
    'compat_methods' => array(
        0 => 'init_query_flags',
        1 => 'parse_tax_query',
    ),
))
```

Comment: Did you debug SQL and try to execute it?

Comment: Yes I have debugged it the query is absolutely right still it reset other filters and return values only of country filter

Comment: If I don't select country everything works best

Comment: Can you add to your question [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) output how your query `$q` looks without and with `country` and how your SQL looks without and with `country`?

Comment: I have edited my question see the var_export results

Comment: @motivast sorry for bad format of var_export result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your `meta_query` param. With and without `country` param.

```
// With country
'meta_query' => array(
    0 => array(
        'key' => '_al_listing_country',
        'value' => array(
            0 => 'Pakistan',
            1 => 'United Kingdom',
        ),
        'compare' => 'IN',
        0 => array(),
        1 => array(
            'key' => '_al_listing_model_name',
            'value' => array(
                0 => 'F12 Berlinetta',
                1 => 'California',
            ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        2 => array(
            'key' => '_al_listing_condition',
            'value' => array(
                0 => 'New',
                1 => 'Used',
            ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        3 => array(),
        4 => array(),
        'relation' => 'AND',
    ),
),

// Without country
'meta_query' => array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(),
        1 => array(
            'key' => '_al_listing_model_name',
            'value' => array(
                0 => 'F12 Berlinetta',
                1 => 'California',
            ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        2 => array(
            'key' => '_al_listing_condition',
            'value' => array(
                0 => 'New',
                1 => 'Used',
            ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        3 => array(),
        4 => array(),
        'relation' => 'AND',
    ),
)
```

Your `key`, `value` and `compare` params are not on the same nesting level just like others `meta_query` filters. This is the problem.

Your country meta_query filter is not in array and is merging with other meta queries in different way. You should return array of array in `country_query` method.

```
/**
 * Returns a meta query for filtering by country.
 * @return type
 */
private function country_query() {

    if ( isset( $_GET['country'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['country'] ) ) {

        $data = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', wp_unslash( $_GET['country'] ) );

        return array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_al_listing_country', 
                'value'   => $data,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        );
    }

    return array();
}
```

or add result from `country_query` as array item like other filters do.

`$country_query[] = $this->country_query();`

Comment: Sir with all due respect i didn't get this part return array(array()); what is this other array that you have added into the return array

Comment: Or which array to pass as all other filters which are working has the exact same code and they are working like a charm

Comment: Sir the part you have edited will return empty array if user have not selected any country at all the other one you are talking about is inside the if condition.

Comment: I have updated my answer to not confuse you. My point is first return statement in if condition. It must be array of array. I don't know how your other filters looks like so I can't speak about them.

Comment: Sir thank you so much for this solution and debugging it for me it means alot to me. Returning array of array resolved my issue and now it is working like a charm